# How could I handle null fields in a SQL table hierarchy?

Tags: sql, powerapps

Say I have a SQL database table containing location information below. These are hierarchies, each level meant to be nested in the level above (Atlanta is a city in Georgia in country USA). Normally, Munich would be in Bavaria, but for whatever reason there's a gap in the hierarchy:

| Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Georgia | Atlanta |
| UK | Lancashire | Manchester |
| Germany | **NULL** | Munich |
| Japan | Kanto | Tokyo |

I want to make the above table look like this below, moving values up to fill in nulls above them:

| Location 1 | Location 2 | Location 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | Georgia | Atlanta |
| UK | Lancashire | Manchester |
| Germany | Munich | **NULL or Munich** |
| Japan | Kanto | Tokyo |

Could this be done with a view, or would copying to a new table be required?

I've considered using PowerApps (the frontend to read from the database) logic to shift the values, but I wanted to take the computing load off the client onto SQL.
If level 2 is blank go to level 3, else add level 2 to list of values. if level 3 is blank, go to level 4, else collect to list of values. So on and so forth.

Comment: You just need to use *coalesce* and either a *case expression* or *nullif* depensing on your RDBMS; I'd consider revising your data model though to a proper parent-child relationship, then adding additional hiercharies becomes easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT location_1, 
  IIF(location_2 IS NULL, location_3, location_2) AS location_2,
  IIF(location_2 IS NULL, CONCAT("NULL or ", location_3), location_3) as 
  location_3 
FROM table1
```

Also note that it's not a good idea for your columns to contain spaces. Try replacing them for underscores.

Comment: Took a bit of adapting, but it seems to work out. Thank you!